# How to merge two hashes in a new hash with the same keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
old_payment_schedule = {"0"=>2083333.3333333335, "1"=>2083333.3333333335, "2"=>2083333.3333333335, "3"=>2083333.3333333335, "4"=>2083333.3333333335, "5"=>2083333.3333333335}
remeasurement_schedule = {"0"=>2291666.6666666665, "1"=>2291666.6666666665, "2"=>2291666.6666666665, "3"=>2291666.6666666665, "4"=>2291666.6666666665, "5"=>2291666.6666666665}
final_result = {"0"=>2083333.3333333335, "1"=>2083333.3333333335, "2"=>2083333.3333333335, "3"=>2083333.3333333335, "4"=>2083333.3333333335, "5"=>2083333.3333333335,"6"=>2291666.6666666665, "7"=>2291666.6666666665, "8"=>2291666.6666666665, "9"=>2291666.6666666665, "10"=>2291666.6666666665, "11"=>2291666.6666666665}
```

Hi everyone I need to comibine two hashes with same keys and different values in a new hash, someone could explain me how to do it, not merge because it will delete values from one hash, I need something as I show in final_result variable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`Hash::[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) to generate the desired hash.

```rb
values = old_payment_schedule.values + remeasurement_schedule.values
keys = (0...arr.length)
final_result = Hash[keys.zip(values)]
#=> {0=>2083333.3333333335, 1=>2083333.3333333335, 2=>2083333.3333333335, 3=>2083333.3333333335, 4=>2083333.3333333335, 5=>2083333.3333333335, 6=>2291666.6666666665, 7=>2291666.6666666665, 8=>2291666.6666666665, 9=>2291666.6666666665, 10=>2291666.6666666665, 11=>2291666.6666666665}
```

Btw, you might want to consider using an array if the hash keys are going to be array indexes.